# MySQL count a number of entries within time period sharing at least 1 of 3 columns

Tags: php, mysql, sql, email

I have a table that logs invalid user login attempts. Every time an invalid attempt is made, the username, user IP, user email and time/date is stored in the database.

What I'd like to do is check if within ANY 24 hour time period there has been more than X invalid attempts by the same user. However, the users can change the email, username or IP at any point. So, I need to check that anyone of these 3 fields is in common.

For example:

- User ID: 1; IP: 1.1.1.1; Email: test@test.com
- User ID: 2; IP: 1.1.1.1; Email: test2@test.com
- User ID: 1; IP: 1.1.1.2; Email: test3@test.com
- User ID: 4; IP: 1.1.1.4; Email: test@test.com
- User ID: 5; IP: 1.1.1.4; Email: test5@test.com

All of these would match as the SAME user because they share EITHER the user ID, the IP or the email. Then I need to output all user IDs, IPs and emails so I can ban any user in another table that matches these criteria.

Comment: If `1.1.1` is consistent with all ID's shown, you can base yourself on the first 3 sets of numbers of the IP address. That seems to be the only close relation to all that you've posted.

Comment: Thanks. The IP was just an example, in reality they will be real and quite variable. These users are still connected in some way because each share an ID, IP or an email with one another. Even id2 and id5 are related because whilst they share no immediate field, they have a second-order relationship via id4 and so forth.

Comment: Ah, I see. Yeah I can see how Gordon's answer explained the complexity in trying to solve the problem. This one's a head banger.

Answer (score 3):

What you have is a graph of connections between records, where the edges are email, username, and IP. You need to traverse this graph to find connected subgraphs. This is difficult. In your example, for instance, id2 and id2 are connected, but they have no fields in common.

So, you need a graph walking algorithm. MySQL does not have constructs that support such algorithms directly in SQL. You can write a stored procedure to find such groups, but this is not something you can do with a single SQL statement.

EDIT:

When I've encountered this problem before, I have used SQL, with repeated `update` statements. The idea is to assign to each record the lowest userid encountered.

```
create table tgroup as
    select t.*, id as grpid
    from table t;

update tgroup join
       (select email, min(id) as minid
        from tgroup t
        group by email
       ) tt
       on tt.email = tgroup.email and
          tt.minid < tgroup.id
    set tgroup.id = least(tt.minid, tgroup.id);

update tgroup join
       (select ip, min(id) as minid
        from tgroup t
        group by ip
       ) tt
       on tt.ip = tgroup.ip and
          tt.minid < tgroup.id
    set tgroup.id = least(tt.minid, tgroup.id);
```

You then have to repeat this until nothing gets updated.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. Would you have any recommendations for such an algorithm in PHP? I was thinking of something with arrays, but I can't wrap my head around it.